# dc.js - Listening for chart group render

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to refactor some custom d3 code that I wrote to render a series of crossfilter-driven charts by bringing in dc.js.

My main problem is that I have some chart types that are not supported by dc.js (e.g. a [Sunburst Partition](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423)) and I'm trying to figure out how to render them in conjunction with a dc.js chart group.

Filtering a single dc.js chart will automatically render / redraw all other charts belonging to the same [chartGroup](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#chartgroupgroup). Is it possible to somehow hook into that global re-render event, so that I can re-draw the non-dc charts at the same time?

I understand that there are listeners on each individual chart, e.g. `chart.on("postRender", function(chart){...})` but there doesn't seem to be a way to hook into re-rendering a group of charts. Is there a good pattern by which this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "right" way to do this is to register your chart in the dc registry with [dc.registerChart](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/global.html#registerChart)

You just need to implement `.redraw()` and `.render()` on some object (your chart or a wrapper), and pass that object as the first argument.

Put it in the same group (second arg) as the charts it should respond to.

[render()](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#render) creates the dom elements from scratch, and [redraw()](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#redraw) updates them when the data changes.

Depending on how the chart is used, you may also have to implement [.filterAll()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#filterAll) and [.anchorName()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#anchorName)

Comment: Thanks! This does seem like the cleanest way. I was going to simply listen to the redraw event on a random one of the dc charts like someone suggested in the dc.js user group, but that is admittedly a bit hackish ;-) I will give it a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I believe there is also `.refocusAll()` for when the zoom level / focus range is reset on a chart group.

Comment: And if you want to participate in deregistering your chart you will need to provide a `.anchorName()` function that returns some kind of guid. I just generate a random integer with `Math.random() * 1000000 << 0;` in the constructor and save it as a member and I return that from my anchorName. Kind of a home-made `_dcFlags` identifier. Anything will work its just used as a key to remove it from the registry.

Comment: Would you please also provide an example? It is difficult to find one...

Comment: @user3329081, sorry for the slow reply. [Here is one minimal example](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.graph.js/blob/develop/timeline.js). Also you can look at the source for some of the really simple widgets, like the [number display](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/number-display.js), although you don't really need to derive from any of the dc.js base classes in order to be compatible with dc.js.

Comment: added simplest possible example here:  https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/custom-chart.html