# use mapbox on dc.js as choropleth map?

Tags: mapbox, dc.js

Can we use mapbox embedded iframe map which created before on mapbox with dc.js?

Comment: I don't know how to do this, or what level of integration you're looking for, but if you want the map to respond to the other charts, this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336528/dc-js-listening-for-chart-group-render/25351686#25351686

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Gordon.Infact I am wondering if we can use dc filtering with other charts or not.For example highcharts charts  and mapbox also.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible but I don't know if anyone has written the glue code to make it happen. That's why I linked to instructions to plug other charts in as if they were dc.js charts.