# Crossfilter compatible charting libraries/ DC.js Alternatives

Tags: nvd3.js, dc.js, crossfilter, dimple.js, c3.js

Has anyone managed to integrate or has got any idea if it is possible to use crossfilter with other charting libraries like nvd3 or C3.js?
I know that interactive data exploration is possible with crossfilter using dc.js library but I am still curious to know if this is feasible with other libraries.
The essential feature that needs to be implemented is the drill down capability that dc.js natively provides.

As per my understanding it is the dc.render and dc.redraw functions that make the whole user experience interactive. On that note is there any other library out there which provides the same functionality?

DC is a great library but it would be good to know about other options.

Regards

Comment: This answer talks about how to connect external charts to dc. The coupling is actually not that strong. I think it would not be all that hard to attach any other charting library that has transitions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25351686/676195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is theoretically possible, but it depends a lot of whether the other library is built with interactive visualization of coordinated views in mind. You would need to manage picking up any filters/selections, applying those to the proper Crossfilter dimension, and then re-rendering all the charts.