# Dc.js and D3.js chart update

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm using dc.js to draw some charts.

In the d3 code I'm calculating dynamicly the total sum of a few columns and add them then to the pie chart which I draw with d3.js.

This is the code which calculates the total sum of the columns:

```
var pieChart = [];
classesJson.forEach(function(classJson){
    var memDegree = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d){
        return d[classJson.name];
    }).value();
    //console.log(memDegree);
    pieChart.push({name:classJson.name, memDegree:memDegree});
});
```

The drawing for the first time works fine. But when I click elements on the dc.js bar charts the d3.js pie chart didn't update. How can accomplish that the GroupAll values from the above code also update in the d3.js pie chart?

This is the total d3 code for the pie chart:

```
radius = Math.min(300, 234) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.memDegree; });

var svg = d3.select("#membership-degree-pie-chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 234)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 300 / 2 + "," + 234 / 2 + ")");

var pieChart = [];
classesJson.forEach(function(classJson){
    var memDegree = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d){
        return d[classJson.name];
    }).value();
    //console.log(memDegree);
    pieChart.push({name:classJson.name, memDegree:memDegree});
});

pieChart.forEach(function(d) {
    d.memDegree = +d.memDegree;
  });

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(pieChart))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.name); });

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });
```

Comment: Take a look at this question for how to connect external charts to dc.js: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336528/dc-js-listening-for-chart-group-render. Also, since dc.js does have a pie chart and you just need to specify custom data, you might consider using a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-filter-the-data-before-its-charted) to supply the data instead of going from scratch in d3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [listener](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-1.6.0.md#listeners) on the dc chart to detect that is has been filtered and then call your update function for the d3 chart.

```
yourDCChart.on("filtered", function (chart, filter) {
    // update function for d3
    updateD3Chart();
});
```

Comment: Hi Justin, I already tried that and the function call also worked but my problem was, that the values from the crossfilter groupAll function didn't update when I click on an dc.js line chart, therefore the d3 chart didn't update. But if I bind the values from the grouAll function to an dc.js number element (http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/number.html) the value updates. Should the crossfilter values also update if I don't add them to an dc.js chart?

Comment: I created here an working example where you can see my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/zz3gd1fy/2/.

Answer (score 1):

Without fiddle or plnkr it's difficult to tell.
But I have edited your code without testing. Please check if it helps, I have created the change function to update the graph.  you can call change function where you want to update the graph. Hope it helps.

```
      var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
          .data(pie(pieChart))
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "arc")
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.data.name); })
.each(function(d) { this._current = d; }); // store the initial angles;

    g.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function (d) { return d.data.name; });

    //For updating change in data
     function change() {


        pie.value(function(d) { return d.memDegree; }); // change the value function
        g = g.data(pie); // compute the new angles
        g.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", function (a) {
            var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
            this._current = i(0);
            return function (t) {
                return arc(i(t));
            };
        }); // redraw the arcs
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. How I can tell dc.js to update the d3.js graph with the groupAll values, if I click on an dc.js chart? Where should I call then the change function?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, now I created a working example on jsfiddle with a button which calls the change method. But the chart didn't get updated and there is no error in the log. https://jsfiddle.net/bprnq1v8/6/

Comment: Now it works with the button but I have dc.js charts and wanted to add the crossfitler values to the d3.js graph which works. When I change something at a dc.js chart the crossfilter values didn't update, so the d3 chart always stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

I attached D3 draw function for my custom visualizations to dc chart, each time the chart was updated/rendered D3 chart got drawn again :

```
dcTable
.on("renderlet.<renderletKey>", function (d3ChartData) {
  drawD3(d3ChartData)
}
```