# Is there a way to create a parallel coordinate that interacts with dc.js visualizations?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I was searching for a parallel coordinates representation from dc.js, but I could not find any. Is there a way to integrate something like https://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/ with crossfilter in order to make it interact (filter) dc.js charts?

Comment: That would be awesome! I don't have time to try this right now, but the basic idea would be to associate each parallel coordinate dimension with a crossfilter dimension. It should work perfectly with the library you linked, since crossfilter dimensions are very efficient at filtering ranges of values - it's just a matter of listening to the library's filter events. IIUC you would not use crossfilter groups, just dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Gordon. I was trying use it as you mentioned, but I had a hard time trying to make the parallel coordinate read the dimensions. Do you have any hint on that? Observing how the parallel coord read dimensions: "d3.csv('examples/data/cars.csv', function(data) {
  pc1 = d3.parcoords()("#example1")
    .data(data)
    .hideAxis(["name"])...."... Should I, somehow, split different dimensions using crossfilter and than merge than again to, so on, be able to read it in parallel coord?

Comment: I haven't looked at the parcoords library but it looks like you would use [dimension.top(Infinity)](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_top) on *any* of the dimensions to retrieve the records according to all of the current filters. Then you also need to figure out how to implement the filtering yourself, and update the chart whenever a redraw event happens - see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336528/dc-js-listening-for-chart-group-render) for general info on connecting a new chart to dc.js.