# How to make d3.js charts interact with dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

We have multiple charts developed in d3.js. We are creating a dashboard where user can add multiple charts which will be visible in one view.

Is is possible to create interactivity between these charts and dc.js? Or do we need to develop these charts in dc.js again?

Please suggest an alternate in case of No.

Comment: You can use the chart registry, though you'll have to figure out the methods a chart needs to implement. You may just want to search the dc.js mailing list as I think there is some discussion there. Or ask on the list. https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.chartRegistry

Comment: This answer is the best documentation at the moment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25351686/676195. Really only a couple of methods are mandatory.