# Can I send optional fields in crossfilter when i making dimension for color coding perspective in dc.rowChart()?

Tags: javascript, json, dc.js, crossfilter

I recently started to use dc.js for my chart creation because it efficiently use crossfilter instance for event handling across different charts. which made dc.js pretty awesome.

But there is also some disadvantages:

when it comes from group & coloring functionality.

**Note:- I put here sample data for my problem.**

suppose, i have this kind of data. like

```
machine = ["abc_1", "abc_2"]
component = ["comp_1", "comp_2"]
service = ["ser_1", "ser_2", "ser_3", "ser_4"]
```

here, if you watch below it's like nested json or tree hierarchy form where

**machine is depend on component**

```
{ 
    "abc_1":["comp_1", "comp_2"],
    "abc_2": ["comp_1"]
}
```

and **component is depend on service**

```
{
    "comp_1": ["ser_1", "ser_2", "ser_3"],
    "comp_2": ["ser_2", "ser_4"]
}
```

then, i convert all tree form hierarchy json in flat json form which crossfilter have required.

```
[
    {'machine': 'abc_1', 'service_status': 0, 'component': 'comp_2', 'service': 'ser_1', 'component_status': 1}, {'machine': 'abc_1', 'service_status': 1, 'component': 'comp_2', 'service': 'ser_2', 'component_status': 1}, {'machine': 'abc_1', 'service_status': 0, 'component': 'comp_2', 'service': 'ser_3', 'component_status': 1}, {'machine': 'abc_1', 'service_status': 1, 'component': 'comp_2', 'service': 'ser_4', 'component_status': 1}, {'machine': 'abc_1', 'service_status': 1, 'component': 'comp_1', 'service': 'ser_1', 'component_status': 1}, {'machine': 'abc_1', 'service_status': 1, 'component': 'comp_1', 'service': 'ser_2', 'component_status': 1}, {'machine': 'abc_1', 'service_status': 1, 'component': 'comp_1', 'service': 'ser_3', 'component_status': 1}, {'machine': 'abc_1', 'service_status': 0, 'component': 'comp_1', 'service': 'ser_4', 'component_status': 1}, {'machine': 'abc_2', 'service_status': 0, 'component': 'comp_2', 'service': 'ser_1', 'component_status': 0}, {'machine': 'abc_2', 'service_status': 0, 'component': 'comp_2', 'service': 'ser_2', 'component_status': 0}, {'machine': 'abc_2', 'service_status': 0, 'component': 'comp_2', 'service': 'ser_3', 'component_status': 0}, {'machine': 'abc_2', 'service_status': 0, 'component': 'comp_2', 'service': 'ser_4', 'component_status': 0}, {'machine': 'abc_2', 'service_status': 1, 'component': 'comp_1', 'service': 'ser_1', 'component_status': 1}, {'machine': 'abc_2', 'service_status': 1, 'component': 'comp_1', 'service': 'ser_2', 'component_status': 1}, {'machine': 'abc_2', 'service_status': 1, 'component': 'comp_1', 'service': 'ser_3', 'component_status': 1}, {'machine': 'abc_2', 'service_status': 0, 'component': 'comp_1', 'service': 'ser_4', 'component_status': 1}
]
```

at this stage i load my json and started a crossfilter instance

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
```

then i create dimensions here

```
var dim = ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d["component"]; });
var grp = dim.group();
```

when i print this grp by write a custom print function it showing like

```
[
    {"key": "comp_1", value:7 },
    {"key": "comp_2", value:4 }
]
```

now, when i pass this dim & grp in dc.js construct it showing like same. it pickup only particular fields and its count and send to dc construct.
which causes i can't create custom coloring if i want to show running not running status with coloring.

Now, i put this dim & grp in dc.rowChart()

```
dc.rowChart("#abc")
    .dimension(dim)
    .group(grp);

dc.renderAll();
```

when i draw this all bars showing different colors. but i want these colors on the basis of status like 0:"red" & 1:"green".

i can do hack but please suggest me right way to play with it.
i want to make

**donut for machines, 
 rowchart for compoonts, 
 rowchart for services**

and i also want event handling between these charts. 
i will be appreciate only genuine answer.

Comment: Please take a look at crossfilter [reductions](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_reduce) and the [reductio](https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio) library. Then search SO a little more for examples how to use these (the [annotated stock example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) is a great resource too), and update your question once you've put a little more effort into this. Thanks!

Comment: actually, i'm little bit confuse here who handle the dc.js chart events crossfilter or it's a native part of dc.js ?

Comment: because i also want interactivity b/w my charts as you showing in "annotated stock example". and i also intrested if there is a way to write my own addon on the top of crossfilter & dc.js. and i will try with "crossfilter reductions" may be it will work.

Comment: The interactivity is through the dc.js chart registry. If you're looking to addon your own chart type, this answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25351686/676195