# Make a custom chart / plot with dc.js, d3.js and crossfilter

Tags: dc.js

I want to create my own chart with `d3.js` and use it with `dc.js` such that I can interact with the chart along with other charts with `crossfilter` support. Is there any way to do so?

To be exact I want to show a graph like in [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slundberg/shap/master/docs/artwork/boston_summary_plot.png).

Comment: We could really use a tutorial for this, but until then here's the canonical Q&A for this. Lmk if you have any questions. The [users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/dc-js-user-group) is a great place for longer conversations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dc.js - Listening for chart group render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336528/dc-js-listening-for-chart-group-render)