# DC.js Map Overlay

Tags: d3.js, maps, overlay, dc.js

I have data with latitude and longitude information. I want to plot the route on a world map using these latitude and longitude values. This is my first attempt at creating a map chart in dc.js.

Are there any examples I can refer to in dc.js to create a visualization similar to [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5851933).

Comment: There is a bubble overlay and a choropleth in dc.js core, and there is dc.leaflet.js, but I don't know of any dc-compatible charting library that draws routes out-of-the-box. Is the route actually going to be filtered using dc.js charts or widgets? If it isn't filtered (or supposed to filter anything else) then you might just go with straight D3 or Leaflet here.

Comment: I can manage with D3 for now. But I will definitely have a requirement for filtering in the future.

Comment: So the individual items that you will draw/hide in response to filtering are the segments/arcs? I think you should first decide whether to draw the underlying map with D3 or with Leaflet. Then you could accordingly work with the Snowden great arcs example for D3 or with something like [Leaflet.Arc](https://github.com/mad-gooze/Leaflet.Arc) for leaflet. Although it would be cool to add this feature to one of the dc libraries, if you don't want to put in that much effort, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25351686/676195) to learn how to connect an external chart to dc.js.

Comment: Ok Gordon. I will check it out and get back to you.