# Integrate any D3.js Chart with DC.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to figure out how to easily integrate any D3.js chart with the DC.js library so as to use the crossfilter feature between all charts.

I also do understand a question of this nature has been asked before, adding the link for reference:

> [DC.js - Listening for chart group render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336528/dc-js-listening-for-chart-group-render)

I was unable to understand or follow the answer and the following comment threads where @Gordon even gave a small minimal example.

Can anyone help me out by putting out a sample code to better understand as to how I could do this? Let us say I would like to integrate [a parallel coordinates D3.js chart](https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281) with [a basic DC.js Pie chart](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/pie.html).

It would be really helpful to see a small basic example as to how to go about to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Parallel coordinates is a difficult case because you want to show every data point (no aggregation), and of course it is showing N dimensions where the ordinary chart uses only 1. I started an attempt [here](https://github.com/gordonwoodhull/dc.parallel-coordinates.js) but I ran into problems with updates. This uses one of the more popular libraries for parallel coordinates, parcoord-es, which I think goes back to an earlier version of Davies' code.

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for examples is not an appropriate use of SO, and there is no short answer to this question, so let's take this discussion to [the users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/dc-js-user-group), please.

Comment: [discussion continued on users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/dc-js-user-group/5KeBs1gyQaA)

Comment: I would like to have an example of integrating an external chart in dc.js beyond the silly [color swatch example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/custom-chart.html) but both parallel coordinates and horizon charts have their own complications which make them not good general examples. (They wouldn't educate anyone, they would just confuse people.)