# dc.js - Chart not rendering (single row bar chart - horizontal row), with the exception of legend, axes and tick marks/values (which do render)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

**Scenario**

I want to see my dc.js horizontal row stacked bar chart (single row chart), but no chart appears, except for legend with names, axes with tick marks which do appear.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Data set below in code snippet

**Question**

How do I render the ensure chart rendering successfully using dc.js / d3.js?

**Code Snippet**

```
$scope.avgCycleTime = function(){


    var data = [ 
                    {"Project":"Expedition","Stage": "Created", "Days":12},
                    {"Project":"Expedition","Stage": "Active", "Days":14},
                    {"Project":"Expedition","Stage": "Closure", "Days":2}
    ];
    var ndx = crossfilter(data);

    data.forEach(function(x) {
      x.Days = 0;
    });

    var ndx = crossfilter(data)

    var xdim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.Days;}); 

    function root_function(dim,stack_names) {
        return dim.group().reduce(
      function(p, v) {
        stack_names.forEach(stack_name => {
          if(v[stack_name] !== undefined)
              p[stack_name] = (p[v[stack_name]] || 0) + v[stack_name]
        });
        return p;}, 
      function(p, v) {
        stack_names.forEach(stack_name => {
          if(v[stack_name] !== undefined)
              p[stack_name] = (p[v[stack_name]] || 0) + v[stack_name]
        });
        return p;}, 
      function() {
        return {};
      });}

    var stages = ['Created', 'Active', 'Closure'];
    var ygroup = root_function(xdim,stages)

    function sel_stack(i) {
    return function(d) {
      return d.value[i];
    };}

    cycleChart = new dc.barChart("#risk-cycle-chart");


    var chart = document.getElementById('risk-cycle-chart'); 


    heightStatusChart =  200;
    widthStatusChart = Math.floor(parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(chart, null).width))
     - 2*parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(chart, null).getPropertyValue('padding-top'));    


    cycleChart
      .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,7,14,21,28]))
      .dimension(xdim)
      .group(ygroup, data[0].Project, sel_stack(data[0].Project))
      .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
      .margins({left:75, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 20})
      .width(widthStatusChart) 
      .height(heightStatusChart)
      .legend(dc.legend());


    for(var i = 1; i<stages.length; ++i)
      cycleChart.stack(ygroup, stages[i], sel_stack(stages[i]));
```

}

Comment: Can you please create a working instance of your issue ?

Comment: Example was almost complete; it just needed the html for the `risk-cycle-chart`, and the chart constructor was using the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to not using a vector graphics generator like d3/dc for this grid portion and instead created a table like so.

[image: Table]

```
 $scope.avgCycleTime = function(){


    var data = [ 
                    {"Project":"Expedition","Stage": "Created", "Days":12, "Color": "rgb(166, 206, 227)"},
                    {"Project":"Expedition","Stage": "Active", "Days":14, "Color": "rgb(253, 180, 98)"},
                    {"Project":"Expedition","Stage": "Closure", "Days":2, "Color": "rgb(179, 222, 105)"}
    ];


    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

    // table row creation
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
      // create element <td> and text node 
      //Make text node the contents of <td> element
      // put <td> at end of the table row
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      cell.setAttribute('style', 'width: ' + data[i].Days * 100 + "px; background-color: " + data[i].Color);
      var cellText = document.createTextNode(data[i].Stage + " " + data[i].Days);

      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }

    //row added to end of table body
    tblBody.appendChild(row);

      // append the <tbody> inside the <table>
      tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
      // put <table> in the <body>
      document.querySelector("#risk-cycle-chart").appendChild(tbl);



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sigh, I guess dc.js and crossfilter have a steep learning curve. There isn't any "interesting" problem here, just a bunch of minor glitches:

1. `dc.barChart` is not a constructor. Use either `new dc.BarChart(...)` or `dc.barChart(...)`
2. You are zeroing out `d.Days`, which is the field your dimension uses, so there will only be one bin.
3. Your x scale should match your `xUnits`, so `d3.scaleOrdinal` not `d3.scaleLinear`.
4. You have changed your data from having separate fields for `Created`, `Active`, `Closure` to one field named `Stage`. With this format of data, your reducers could look like

   ```
   function root_function(dim, stack_field, stack_names) {
     return dim.group().reduce(
       function(p, v) {
         p[v[stack_field]] = p[v[stack_field]] + 1; // 2
         return p;},
       function(p, v) {
         p[v[stack_field]] = p[v[stack_field]] - 1; // 3
         return p;}, 
       function() {
         return Object.fromEntries(stack_names.map(sn => [sn,0])); // 1
       });}
   ```

   1. Initialize each bin with a field for each of the `stack_names` with value 0
   2. When adding a row to a bin, determine which field it affects using `stack_field`; increment that field
   3. When removing a row from a bin, decrement the same way
5. You are requesting an x domain of `[0,7,14,21,28]` but none of your `Days` fall exactly on those values. If you want to round down, you could do

   ```
   var xdim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return Math.floor(d.Days/7)*7;});
   ```
6. `.group(ygroup, data[0].Project, sel_stack(data[0].Project))` doesn't make sense since you are stacking by `Stage`, not by `Project`; this should be `.group(ygroup, stages[0], sel_stack(stages[0]))`

With the above changes, we get a chart with one stack in each of the first three bins:

[image: screenshot of working chart]

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/umngfp9h/24/).

Comment: Wow!!   Thank you once more Gordon,  Can you suggest how I control animation of the bars to width horizontally, not diagonally up on load, if this can by modified some way or via css?   How do I shift the horizontal tick marks to have the "0" appear centered on the y axis line not 3.5 units to the right of the y axis.

Comment: Also, day's (12,14, 2) determine width of each of the stacked rectangles corresponding to the horizontal units.  Example I am trying to piece together. 
  https://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/418d3f6d91915602e4fd

Comment: Oh I guess you should have specified that in your question. Variable width bars are not supported, sorry.

Comment: It’s hard to control the animation. Not sure if it’s possible to uncenter the bars for an ordinal scale, might have to use a linear scale and appropriate xUnits.

Comment: To the point about, variable widths, am I able to use d3 to modify at the end of the function?

Comment: Maybe, but it sounds too difficult. You're probably better off [adapting the D3 chart to dc.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336528/dc-js-listening-for-chart-group-render) than changing both the position and size of the bars in dc.js - I mean, there's hardly anything left of dc.js once you do that.

Comment: Placing a single row variable cell (3 cells) width table solved my issue.  See answer below.

Comment: Oh I see. Sure, if you only need one dimension, that’s a lot easier. Thanks for posting your solution! (I don’t understand how it relates to your question, but that’s cool. Asking the right question is a tough problem in itself!)